# Memoir rounds down textwidth to nearest pt after checkandfixthelayout

Tags: memoir

Using memoir with LuLaTeX, I noticed that `\checkandfixthelayout` rounds down `textwidth` to the nearest pt. How can I prevent this rounding? In the example below, I'm missing 0.35 pt from `textwidth`.

Edit:

I looked at memoir.cls (v3.7f, 2016/05/16) line number 1295 and found that `\textwidth` is actually rounded down to the nearest pt with `\@settopoint`. My problem disappeared by commenting out that line. I also commented out the two next ones that did the same to `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin`. I wonder if this is safe. I also wonder why the code is like this in the first place. Why round down? I want to set `\textwidth` exactly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}

\settrims{0mm}{0mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{127mm}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout  % options: fixed, classic, lines, nearest

\begin{document}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\spinemargin+\textwidth+\foremargin}%
\noindent spinemargin + textwidth + foremargin =\\ \the\spinemargin\ + \the\textwidth\ + \the\foremargin\ = \the\mylength

\ \newline
paperwidth = \the\paperwidth
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the next `memoir` release there will be a class option to disable this truncation feature.

Comment: Bumped into this issue today. What's the status about this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for others how are interested. The safest way to "ignore" `\@settopoint` in this case is probably the code below.

I asked Peter Wilson, the `memoir` author. The only reason he had what that it looked better when printed. But then again it is only done for some lengths.

In a future version we'll probably rewrite this such that the use of `\@settopoint` is something that is easier to remove.

```
\makeatletter
\let\normalsettopoint\@settopoint
% this just writes the lengths that would be adjustsed to log
\def\@settopoint#1{\typeout{\string#1}}
\makeatother
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

% run margins as soon as possible
\setlength{\textwidth}{127mm}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout  % options: fixed, classic, lines, nearest
% restore \@settopoint just if other packages rely on it, has to go
% AFTER margin adjustments
\makeatletter
\let\@settopoint\normalsettopoint
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylength}

\setlength{\mylength}{\dimexpr\spinemargin+\textwidth+\foremargin}%

spinemargin + textwidth + foremargin =

\the\spinemargin\ + \the\textwidth\ + \the\foremargin\ = \the\mylength


\bigskip


paperwidth = \the\paperwidth

 \end{document}
```